# Pass Keep me signed in (KMSI) as an output claim in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Our client wants to receive Keep me signed in (KMSI) as an output claim in Azure AD B2C.

We haven’t had any luck implementing this request. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Stepping through the user journey and looking at the network and B2C trace we noticed the **rememberMe** query string. We thought of using this as an alternative solution, but we couldn’t make this persist until the end.

```
https://aadb2c.onmicrosoft.com/aadb2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_SignIn/api/SignIn/confirmed?rememberMe=true&csrf_token=loremIpsum&tx=StateProperties=loremIpsum&p=B2C_1A_SignIn&diags=loremIpsum
```

Comment: You want to pass KMSI as a claim in access token? Where did you find the "rememberMe"? Please add more details.

Comment: Hi @AllenWu, yes we wanted to pass it as an output claim. We found the rememberMe query string from the network trace (sample URL in the description).